# How to create an online rebol console?

Tags: rebol

Where can I find the code for creating an online rebol console like the one here ?
http://tryrebol.esperconsultancy.nl/

Update: for the sandbox system on the server, can't Rebol manage it itself with some security wrapper and its security options ?

As for console itself, I don't know Ruby so I don't want to use TryRuby and why would I need it ? Can't I mimic Rebol console itself by "remoting" it somehow ? Why RT or Esper Consultancy can't make an   opensource version ? There's no value in keeping it closed source. Rebol needs to prove it's more open than in the past.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, you should aim higher with something like the already open-sourced [Try Ruby](https://github.com/Sophrinix/TryRuby).  You'd type in expressions and it would guide you.  Their showcase site is at [tryruby.org](http://tryruby.org) and is fairly slick.

I modified TryRuby to work with Rebol and it wound up looking like this:
[image]

But I'm not going to run it on my server because I didn't want to belabor the necessary sandboxing/etc. or protections against someone running an infinite loop.  I can give you what I've got so far if you want it.

I started a tutorial script here that no one seemed interested in helping me with, so I wandered off to other tasks:

http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Interactive_tutorial_script

Comment: Hi HostileFork my purpose is not to use it for tutorials but for real remote command line. There are a lot of basic tutorials on rebol, people need REAL WORLD samples now and that is what is missing in Rebol Ecosystem. So I need this for real scenario and what should be documented is how to setup the whole stuff as for security. By the way why can't rebol itself manage a sandbox system ?

Comment: I don't know Ruby and why would I need it ? Can't I mimic Rebol console itself by "remoting" it somehow ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what exactly you want. You mention you want a remote REBOL shell instead of a tutoring setup, but that's what the Try REBOL site is. There are several reasons it's not open source:

- It's in heavy development. I'm currently changing the code regularly.
- So it's not in a release state. Preparing it for release, documenting and publishing it would take a lot of extra work, as with most projects.
- It's written in my CMS that's also in heavy development. Even if the Try REBOL site were open source, it wouldn't run. The CMS is not planned to be open sourced soon.
- It's not meant as a generic REBOL remoting tool, but as a one-off demo site. If that site is running, what's the use of more of them?

As others have answered, there are many generic solutions for remoting that you could use. Also, most parts of the Try REBOL site are readily available as open source:

- Syllable Server, produced and published by us.
- The Cheyenne web server.
- The HTML source of the web client can be viewed, including my simple JavaScript command service bus.

Syllable Server is an essential part of the site, as the sandboxing is not done with REBOL facilities (except some extra limits in the R3 backend), but with standard Linux facilities.

Comment: Hello Kaj, first time I "encounter" you so how do you do :) Sorry I didn't mean to be aggressive but the aim of Opensource is to share the burden of development with others. So why do you say it's a heaby development and keep all on your shoulders ? I won't be able to help as I'm novice but I'm sure a lot of rebol gurus would be pleased to look and contribute to it.

Answer (score 3):

A truly air tight (do I mean silica tight?) sandbox is close to impossible with R2.

R3 (still in alpha) is looking a lot more promising. The deep technical discussions in flight right now (see [Cure code](http://www.curecode.org/rebol3/view-tickets.rsp) and [AltME/REBOL3 Proposals](http://www.rebol.org/aga-display-posts.r?post=r3wp824x1) regarding **unwinds** and **protect** and even occasionally mentioning **sandboxes** should lead to an excellent sandbox capability.

Right now, the big advance R3 has that makes Kaj's **tryREBOL** possible is R3's [secure](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/secure.html) **policy settings** which make it possible (with some careful wrapper code) to construct an alpha/demo sandbox.

To answer your precise question(**"where can I find code..."**, you could try asking Kaj for his :)

Comment: Thanks I don't know Kaj but such app should obviously been opensourced like TryRuby. If rebol wants to be evangelised it's not just through press release and short tutorials or libraries but real world app short enough to be studied not like cheyenne which is too big. These real world are really missing in rebol.

Comment: Note that Kaj's re-invokes the interpreter each time.  So if in one line you do `x: 10`, then hit evaluate, then do `print x`... it will say x is undefined.  I think he gives an expression a certain amount of time to evaluate before killing it.  To do a persistent interpreter which holds state between commands like TryRuby you need some kind of session management.  That means dealing with issues like cleaning up interpreters which are no longer in use.

Comment: I've alerted Kaj to this question so, if he wants to enter into it, he can....As to whether any of someone's code should be "obviously" open source, that's a discussion of marketing models that (is probably) taking place elsewhere on SO; meanwhile, the opportunity is still there for someone to create an open source REBOl console application.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to StackOverflow. I'm not sure if this is going to end up as a reply to your comment, or as a new answer.

The somewhat common idea that any project can be open sourced and contributed to by others is a naive view. In the case of my Try REBOL site, it makes no sense. It's not just in heavy development; it's written in a CMS that's also in heavy development. Basically noone could contribute to it at this point, because I'm the only one who knows my CMS. Or in any case its newest features, which I develop by developing Try REBOL, and other example sites. So developing Try REBOL means developing the CMS at the same time, and by definition, I'm the only one who can do that.

More generally, my projects are bleeding edge, innovative technology with a strong vision. The vision is mine, and to teach it to others, I have to build it to show how I intended it to work. So there's a catch 22: to enable others to contribute, I have to finish my projects first, because people typically don't understand them until I show them how they work.

There certainly are other projects where mass contribution makes more sense. Still, only the top projects get the contributors. We found that out the hard way. We created Syllable Desktop and Syllable Server with surrounding infrastructure for contributions. These are fairly classic, well understood operating systems that many people could work on in parallel. However, despite years of begging, we get very few contributions.

So, if you feel a burning need to contribute to our projects, please pick one of the many tasks in Syllable to execute. :-)